# How to Splice Delphi FireDAC Query Code at Design Time

Tags: delphi, firedac

I am getting this syntax error message:

```
[FireDAC][Phys][SQLite] ERROR: near "ON": syntax ERROR
```

On my code here:

```
  qryItems.Active := False;
  qryItems.ResourceOptions.ParamCreate := False;
  qryItems.SQL.Text := 'SELECT category.name, item.name, item.description' +
                       'FROM item ' +
                       'JOIN category ON item.category_id = category.list_id' +
                       'WHERE item.name = :searches OR :searches IS NULL' +
                       'ORDER BY category.name LIMIT 5';
  qryItems.ParamByName('searches').AsString := Format('%%%s%%',[edtSearch.Text]);
  qryItems.Active := True;
  qryItems.SQL.Clear;
  qryItems.ExecSQL;
```

I tried running the code in Query Editor of TFDQuery with no issues. I am compelled to slice the query to avoid long text violations with this syntax '+' — I hope this is still the practice.

It looks like nothing is wrong with my syntax. Otherwise, I miss something here.

Comment: You just forgot to add spaces.

Comment: Just check(debug) `qryItems.SQL.Text` at runtime and you will see the missing spaces.

Comment: @Juke: There **ARE** errors with your syntax. I see three of them. You're missing a space between `item_description` and `FROM` in the first two lines, between `category.list_id` and `WHERE` on the next line, and between `NULL` and `ORDER` on the next two lines. Uwe's answer below identifies those three errors perfectly, too. Try again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The SQL lines end up like this (note the JOIN, WHERE and ORDER, **highlighted for emphasis**):

> SELECT category.name, item.name, **item.descriptionJOIN** category ON item.category_id = **category.list_idWHERE** item.name = :searches OR :searches IS **NULLORDER** BY category.name LIMIT 5

You can set SQL with multiple lines like this:

```
  qryItems.SQL.Clear;
  qryItems.SQL.AddStrings(TArray<string>.Create(
      'SELECT category.name, item.name, item.description',
      'JOIN category ON item.category_id = category.list_id',
      'WHERE item.name = :searches OR :searches IS NULL',
      'ORDER BY category.name LIMIT 5'));
```

Perhaps declaring a constant my increase readability:

```
const
  cSQL: TArray<string> = [
    'SELECT category.name, item.name, item.description',
    'JOIN category ON item.category_id = category.list_id',
    'WHERE item.name = :searches OR :searches IS NULL',
    'ORDER BY category.name LIMIT 5'];
...
  qryItems.SQL.Clear;
  qryItems.SQL.AddStrings(cSQL);
```

Comment: Thank you for giving more than just an answer. However, I am getting this time this error [FireDAC][Phys][SQLite] ERROR: near "JOIN": syntax ERROR. I tried all the script you gave including the "space" issue. Also, I tried debugging the qryItems.SQL.Text and got the message "Source File not Found: FireDAC.Stan.Error.pas" at step-in F7 but if I step-in F8 "Source File not Found: FireDAC.Comp.Client.pas.". I hope this is not getting deeper.

Comment: I usually work around this issue (the omission of spaces during concatenation) by explicitly ending each line with `'#13 +`, because the addition of the CR (#13) removes the need to add the extra space.

Comment: @KenWhite I see. I will try that. Thanks for sharing. However, I already figured out the error. I forgot to put the FROM ITEM. Whew! really really my bad. The answer of UweRaabe works! Thanks so much to all who shared their thoughts.